# Validate Tomcat Authentication in rest client

Tags: java, tomcat, restful-authentication, rest-client

I am using rest full web service and tomcat security. I want to write a restclient which will provide the username and password and will do authentication in server.

Please suggest some ways how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is through basic HTTP authentication.
You'll need to modify two files:

1.`web.xml` of your application. Add:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Basic authentication</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
  <description>Some role description</description>
  <role-name>role1</role-name>
</security-role>
```

2.`tomcat-users.xml` in `conf` directory:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <user name="user1" password="pass" roles="role1" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Thanks daniel. Can't it possible without modifying the web.xml?

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161600/centrally-secure-all-tomcat-webapps-using-basic-authentication

Comment: Rakesh, if the response worked for you, please rate it. Otherwise let me know the problem. Thanks!