# Tomcat authentication and specific web app authentication

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, authentication, basic-authentication

I config my tomcat with the following configuration in the web.xml. So now I secure all webapps in the folder webapps. The user has to authenticate himself, before he can visit the web apps.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>
      My Application
    </web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>demo123</role-name>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Secure Apps</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

After the user logged in, he can visit the requested web app. 
My problem:
In the web apps the user have to logged in (with Basic authentication), because behind there is a specific server with all server logic. I use REST Webservices to communicate to that server. But I can't call the webservices because it shows me a 401 Unauthorized.
If I delete the above configuration in the web.xml, I can call these webservices without problems.
Is there a way to secure all webapps in the tomcat another way? I need it because the webapps needs the basic authentication.

For the applications I use spring framework.

Comment: A user must login to access the webapps and then must login to the webapp it self?

Comment: Yes, the first login is for the security, so guests can never visit the webapps.. the second login is the login at the web app with the specific server.

Comment: Why is the login at the webapp not enough?

Comment: The web apps are all for testing and prototyps. So guests in the www should not see the styling and functions. Do you remember it? Or is it the wrong way? The web apps should be secured by our team.

Comment: Only I have to secure the web apps, so guests can't see the web apps. I have done it with this one. Is there an another way to secure it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161600/centrally-secure-all-tomcat-webapps-using-basic-authentication

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's the right or wrong way. The REST Webservices call from a client or from ajax? if it's a client app try calling the services like `https://gooduser:secretpassword@www.example.com/webcallback?foo=bar`

Comment: I have a Spring Controller and within an object 'RESTful Java Client'. The RESTful Java Client is auto-generated and call the methods of the REST Webservice. I don't know if it's from client or server. The Webservices are lying on the tomcat server with all webapps, too.

Comment: you must find a way to access the webservice urls without auth. perhaps this helps `http://blog.mafr.de/2011/04/17/excluding-pages-from-auth/`

Comment: Mhh, that does not work. I put my subfolder to the url-pattern like '/public_folder/*', but the authentication is still needed. Is something missing?

Comment: Ok now I put the extensions like .html and so on to the url-pattern. It's working, because the Webservices don't have any extensions. Thank you for your ideas, Hank Lapidez!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with changing the url-pattern.